# Hi! Can someone please help me figure out why and how this query works? I can't understand the logic behind it. Thanks so much

Tags: sql, trim

[Screenshot illustrating the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPx4E.png)

**TASK**: separate the `location` column into two columns for latitude and longitude.

Location column:

```
(37.709725805163, -122.413623946206)
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    location,
    TRIM(leading '(' FROM LEFT(location, POSITION(',' IN location) - 1)) AS latitude,
    TRIM(trailing ')' FROM RIGHT(location, LENGTH(location) - POSITION(',' IN location) ) ) AS longitude
FROM 
    tutorial.sf_crime_incidents_2014_01
```

**PROBLEM**: I want to know why this query works because I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: It's called Mode. I'm putting a link to it right here https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-string-functions-for-cleaning

Comment: Find the position of the comma. Get the stuff to the left of it and trim off the leading `(` and you get the latitude. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read it from the outside in. It helps to space it all out.

```
TRIM(
  leading '(' FROM 
    LEFT(
      location, 
      POSITION(',' IN location) - 1
    )
)
```

`POSITION(',' IN location)` returns the offset of the first `,` in `location`. In your example `(37.709725805163, -122.413623946206)` that's 17. Subtracting one excludes the comma, 16.

`LEFT(location, POSITION(',' IN location) - 1)` evaluates in your example to `left(location, 16)` and returns everything in `location` which is left of the given position: first `,` except the comma. `(37.709725805163`.

Finally `TRIM( leading '(' from LEFT(location, POSITION(',' IN location) - 1))` evaluates to `TRIM( leading '(' from` (37.709725805163`)` and removes everything from the string before and including the first '('. `37.709725805163`.

You should be able to figure out the second one.

Comment: Hell yeah. I get it now. Thanks so much, that was a huge help